# WinRT C++ assign a named style to an element programmatically

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I have created several styles in the Application.Resources (App.xaml)

Was going to set these styles dynamically as the app was running.

I can not find a way to read the the App.xaml file in C++.

This is an example of what I have tried:

`ResourceDictionary^ rd = ref new ResourceDictionary();`

rd->Source = ref new Uri("ms-appx:///App.xaml");

Then I can not find any documentation of using the rd object!

I have found a lot of examples of read the resources from C#, but I have found no examples in C++

Even some of the MS documentation says "No code example is currently available or this language may not be supported." WTF!!!!!!

I have no choice in the language the app is being developed in. I am finding it extremely hard to do simple thing with C++/xaml. I have tried the same tests using C#/xaml and this just works (usercontrol binding/template binding with custom controls).

Can anyone give some guidance or direction where to look for this information.

thanks

Comment: Eventually found what I was looking for.

To get the current resources you have to uses:

`auto style = App::Current->Resources->Lookup("msgTextBorderNew");
border->Style =  safe_cast<Windows::UI::Xaml::Style ^>(style );`

The documentation is really bad for C++/xaml/metro.